# What is the behavior of setting timeout in aggregation pipeline execution in MongoDB Java Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb, timeout, aggregation-framework

I need to set a timeout on aggregation pipeline execution. I am using MongoDB Java driver 3.2. I know that the code I have to use is the following:

```
collection.aggregate(pipeline).maxTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The problem is that I cannot find anywhere what is the behavior of the program once the timeout is reached. Does it thrown an exception? Does it terminate silently returning a `null` result?

The official MongoDB documentation says nothing (see [cursor.maxTimeMS()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.maxTimeMS/#cursor.maxTimeMS)). Also the Java API does not refer to any particular behavior (see [maxTime](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html#maxTime-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-)).

How is it possible?!

Comment: I would hope that it would return a null iterable. if you want to test it, just input a very small amount of time that would force an immediate timeout and see what you get.

Comment: I tried. It seems to do nothing at all. The timeout seems to be not respected :(

Comment: so with a small timeout it returned a non null value?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz the timeout exceeding thrown an exception. See my answer for further details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've got it. If the execution of the aggregation pipeline exceeds the time expressed through the method `maxTime` a [`com.mongodb.MongoExecutionTimeoutException`](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoExecutionTimeoutException.html) is thrown.

The stacktrace of the exception is exactly the following:

```
com.mongodb.MongoExecutionTimeoutException: operation exceeded time limit

    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.createSpecialException(ProtocolHelper.java:157)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:111)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocol.execute(CommandProtocol.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:159)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:286)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.command(DefaultServerConnection.java:173)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:215)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CommandOperationHelper.executeWrappedCommandProtocol(CommandOperationHelper.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation$1.call(AggregateOperation.java:227)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation$1.call(AggregateOperation.java:223)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:239)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:212)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation.execute(AggregateOperation.java:223)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AggregateOperation.execute(AggregateOperation.java:65)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:772)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:759)
```

Hope it helps.