# Force timeout on MongoTemplate aggregate API

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there any way to add time out parameter maxTimeMs in the below query? 
I want the aggregation to time out after 1 minutes

```
List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperations = getAggregationOperations();

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(aggregationOperations)
                .withOptions(newAggregationOptions()
                        .cursor(new Document("batchSize", 99))
                        .allowDiskUse(true).build());


List<Document> responseList = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, collectionName, Document.class).getRawResults().get("results", List.class);
```

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162307/what-is-the-behavior-of-setting-timeout-in-aggregation-pipeline-execution-in-mon)

Comment: thats collection.aggregate() query. I used mongoTemplate.aggregate in the question. And there is no maxTime associated with that.
 
@Valijon

Comment: Check this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.mongo-xml-config

Comment: Can you specify this?

Comment: Post here your XML definition for mongo connection

Comment: I do not have any XML definition. using spring-data-mongodb in Spring Boot project

Comment: Last chance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48532163/3710490